# What word describes changing behavior from consuming or using services to contributing or providing?

Tags: single-word-requests

I"m attempting to efficiently describe a threshold of when someone has moved from being a consumer to a contributor.  My context is a church setting.  I'm responsible for drafting a description of the different barriers or thresholds a person encounters or crosses in the process of integrating into a local congregation.

Here is what I have developed so far:

- The first threshold is called *resonance*. This is the process of tentative agreement with the beliefs of the church, initial trust of the church leadership and sensing that this is a place where one can develop rewarding relationships.
- The next threshold is participating in a class or small group and volunteering. I had hoped to find a word with some weight or vibe like "*resonance*." Perhaps *induct*?

Comment: I believe what happens is that a consumer eventually views themselves as a stakeholder, and begins to want to influence how the service is managed.

Comment: At first sight, the word 'threshold' itself seems suitable.Could you give us a sample sentence with a blank where the word would go? The extra context might help. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe 'new responsibilities'?

Comment: Given [***induct***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/induct) *- to introduce, especially to **something requiring special knowledge or experience***, you might consider ***induction*** suitable for describing the process whereby a "help-seeking" new supplicant becomes a "help-giving" established adept.

Comment: I'm listing and describing the different thresholds a guest or attendee passes in the process of integrating into the congregation.  Here is what I have developed so far. The first threshold is called resonance.  This is the process of tentative agreement with the beliefs of the church, initial trust of the church leadership and sensing that this is a place where one can develop rewarding relationships.   The next threshold is participating in a class or small group and volunteering.  I had hoped to find a word with some weight or vibe like "resonance."  I think "induct" could be it.

Comment: Please add all that elaboration to the question. Click [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/263282/edit).

Comment: maybe *commitment* ?

Answer (score 1):

I think of the idiom, "[to give back](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_back)," which is typically followed by the entity that is the beneficiary of the contribution.

Wiktionary Definition:

> (transitive, intransitive, idiomatic) To contribute money, goods or, especially, services for charitable purposes, **as if in return** for one's own success.

Example:

> We organize this Thanksgiving dinner at the old-age home to *give back* to the community.

Naturally, [there is some subjectivity involved in the interpretation of this idiom](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11364/what-should-be-the-proper-term-when-someone-wants-to-give-back-to-the-communit), as well as a [debate](http://www.nytimes.com/roomfordebate/2011/11/29/how-to-spend-the-lottery-winnings/the-meaning-of-giving-back) that surrounds this subjectivity.

I think that "giving back" aptly describes "someone who has moved from being a consumer to a contributor."

Comment: Plus one for the link to that SE question, whose [lowest voted answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11364/what-should-be-the-proper-term-when-someone-wants-to-give-back-to-the-communit/53009#53009) is my favorite: *Pay it forward.*

Answer (score 0):

The verbal phrase *[step up](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/step_up)* is often used to signify such a transition

> (intransitive, idiomatic) To assume responsibility; to volunteer or offer. 
>   *Won't anyone step up to the challenge?*

*Wiktionary*

Comment: I appreciate the idea. That is what I'm looking for, but not the right term (for me) for the context.  See my comments above. I think I'll use the term "Induct" or "Induction" as the label for the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. No single words here, only concepts (perhaps you could just go with **enlightened**).

**[Enlightened self-interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlightened_self-interest)** –Wiki

> Enlightened self-interest is a philosophy in ethics which states that persons who act to further the interests of others (or the interests of the group or groups to which they belong), ultimately serve their own self-interest.

In conjunction with:

**[Delayed gratification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_gratification)** –Wiki

> Delayed gratification, or deferred gratification, is the ability to resist the temptation for an immediate reward and wait for a later reward. Generally, delayed gratification is associated with resisting a smaller but more immediate reward in order to receive a larger or more enduring reward later.

E.g., *eternal life*.

See also, **[Governing dynamics](https://www.google.com/search?q=governing%20dynamics&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)**. Stated loosely: (what is best for the group, is also best for you)

> a stable state of a system that involves several interacting participants in which no participant can gain by a change of strategy as long as all the other participants remain unchanged –[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Governing+dynamics)

“If everyone competes for the blonde, we block each other and no one gets her. So then we all go for her friends. But they give us the cold shoulder, because no one likes to be second choice. Again, no winner. But what if none of us go for the blonde. We don’t get in each other’s way, we don’t insult the other girls. That’s the only way we win.”

–quote from the movie *A Beautiful Mind*, pasted from [netwar.wordpress.com](https://netwar.wordpress.com/2007/08/26/the-real-nash-equilibrium/), titled: *The Real Nash Equilibrium* (a somewhat interesting read, debating the validity of this theory)